# Trying to install scipy to Python 3.4 on OSX 10.9

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy, osx-mavericks

I'm trying to install scipy to python 3.4 on a MacBook Pro OSX 10.9.  I ran:

```
pip3.4 install scipy
```

It gives me a weird error:

```
fatal error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/lipo
: can't figure out the architecture type of:
 /var/folders/0l/3f0sj4850cb89lbn_l1qq3d00000gn/T//ccxqIIEg.out
```

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Forget it...  I think I figured it out.  (It installed anyway.)  Using pip to install scipy pulls a pulls a python 2.7 version of sicpy, not one that works with works python3.  I downloaded a binary for python 3.3 and compiled and it installed.